# Google search form: search inside a domain in browser with no JavaScript support

Tags: html, google-search

Reccently I added a Google Custom Search to my website. It work perfect in browsers with JavaScript supported.
I add code bellow after Google Search box:

```
<noscript>JavaScript disabled... (Sorry, something in other language)</noscript>
```

Now I want insert a form with an

```
<input type="hidden" name="..." value="http://domain" />
```

to `noscript` tag that specific a domain to search. That incase of no JavaScript supported, user still search inside my website.

So: I want ask that is Google Search have any parametter that fit my need? Thank you!

*(Sorry for bad English!)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="http://domain"/>
```